# Changing MKMapType using modal segue with partial curl

Tags: ios, mkmapview, modalviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I am writing an app where I have a mapview displayed. Now I want to give the user the option to change the MKMapType from standard to hybrid.

In oder to do that I created a segue to another view controller containing a switch to set the Map Type. The transition is modal using a partial curl. To access the value of the switch, I introduced a BOOL which is called fotoMode in AppDelegate. If this variable is set to YES (and if the switch is set to ON) then I'd like to redraw the map.

```
- (IBAction) FotoModusSwitchChanged:(UISwitch *)sender 
{
 AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];    
if(sender.isOn)
 {
    appDelegate.fotoMode=YES;
 }
 else 
 {
    appDelegate.fotoMode=NO;
 }
}
```

I have included the following lines of code in VieWillAppear, ViewDidAppear, ViewDidLoad, ViewWillLayoutSubviews of the view controller for the Map View but it does not work:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];    
if (appDelegate.fotoMode) {
    [self.MapOutlet setMapType:MKMapTypeHybrid];
}
else
{
    [self.MapOutlet setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

PS: Setting the MKMapType manually to Hybrid or Standard works...

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `if (appDelegate.fotoMode)` and when the debugger stops there, check the value of `appDelegate.fotoMode`.  Also check whether `self.MapOutlet` is `nil` at that point.

Comment: I did that and the MapOutlet is not nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code seems right to me but I think you're having problem with declaration of the "fotoMode".

Make sure that under your Appdelegate.h file you define your BOOL

@property(nonatomic,assign) BOOL fotoMode;

if you don't declare your BOOL right then you wont' be able to set and get the right value.

Hope helps...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I declared fotoMode in Appdelegate.h as you said. Then I added an NSLog to to see whether the value of fotoMode changed when the switch.isOn changed. And it does. However, none of the methods in the view controller with the MapView (VieWillAppear, ViewDidAppear, ViewDidLoad, ViewWillLayoutSubviews) is called when I leave the view which is shown below the curled MapView and go back to the map. Should I use another method that is called after leaving returning to the mapView?

Comment: I have created this app and I used the code you provided and it works. I put your code into -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated method and the map changes hybrid/standart when I swtich the button ON/OFF. SO I'm not sure what you're missing. I would suggest you to check your connections on IB. Again I have just tested and everything works.

Comment: Thanks. I am using a UNavigationController and I believe this is the issue. Probably the Navigation Controller is doing the drawing of the Map View and hence the -viewWillAppear a.s.o. methods of the Map View are not called. This is confirmed by the fact that when I change the switch, pop the Map View and push it again, the code also works. So I guess my initial problem is solved. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I solved the issue with the NavigationController as follows: 1. Create a UINavigationController class and connect it to the Navigation Controller in the storyboard. 2. implement the following method in the NavigationViewController - (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
{
    [self performfotoModeCheck];
    [super dismissViewControllerAnimated:flag completion:completion];
} <continue to read next post>

Comment: The - (void) performfotoModeCheck method looks like this:   if ([[self.viewControllers lastObject] isKindOfClass:[MapViewController class]])
    {
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        MapViewController * mvc = (MapViewController*) [self.viewControllers lastObject] ;
        
        if (appDelegate.fotoMode) {
            [mvc.MapOutlet setMapType:MKMapTypeHybrid];
        }
        else
        {
            [mvc.MapOutlet setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
        }
    }
This works now.

Answer (score 0):

ViewWill/DidAppear does not get called when partial curl is closed (since old view never fully disappeared). Use delegation to call when you close the settings page.